# Set theory: If $C \cup B = U$, $D \cup F = U$ and $B \cap D = \emptyset$, then $C \cup F = U$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So far I have: let $x$ exist in $C \cup F$, then $x$ is in $C$ or $x$ is in $F$. Then since $C \cup B = U$ and $D \cup F = U$, $x$ is in $C$ or $x$ is in $B$ AND $x$ is in $D$ or $x$ is in $F$. But because $B \cap D = \emptyset$, we know $x$ is not in $B$ or $D$.

Comment: What does "=U" mean??? Equal to the union symbol? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you mean a universal set? If so, then it's confusing because you use both a capital "U" for the union symbol and the universal set.

Comment: Sorry! I don't know how to edit in the fancy symbols. But it's equal to the universal set.

Comment: OK, now it makes sense. I'll edit it for you.

Answer (score 1):

(1)The assertion  by the O.P: ".... x is not in B or D" is wrong..... (2)To show that $u=c\cup f$ it suffices to show that no $x\in u$ can satisfy both $x\not \in c$  and $x\not \in f$. This is true because $$x\in u\backslash c \to x\in b$$ while $$x\in u\backslash f \to x\in d.$$ So if both of these held, we would have $x\in b\cap d=\phi.$

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that for any $x \in U$, if $x \notin C$ then $x \in F$. So suppose $x \notin C$. As $C \cup B = U$, we must have $x \in B$. Because $B \cap D = \emptyset$, it follows that $x \notin D$. Finally, from the assumption $D \cup F = U$ we can conclude that $x \in F$.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following implications:

- $B\cup C = U \implies \overline{C}\subset B$.
- $F\cup D = U \implies \overline{F}\subset D$.

So $\overline{C\cup F} = \overline{C}\cap \overline{F}\subset B\cap D = \emptyset$. This proves that $C\cup F = U$.